# Maximal subgroups of the additive and multiplicative groups Q.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was working on the following problem:

> (a) Prove that the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$ has no maximal proper subgroups.
>   (b) Is the same statement true for the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Q}^\times$?

So, for part (a) I decided I would assume that $M$ was a maximal group and seek a contradiction. Unfortunately, I couldn't see a whole lot to do since a additive subgroup does not even need to have a minimal positive element, but I decided to write $M = \left<a_i/i\right> $ where $a_i$ is the minimal positive integer such $a_i/i \in M$ for each $i$.
Since $M$ is maximal, it must be the case that some $a_i > 1$. I wanted to show that adding in $1/i$ would create another proper subgroup that contains $M$, but I couldn't quite do it.

For (b), I have no idea :(.

Comment: Have you looked at the quotient group of a putative maximal proper subgroup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be maximal in $\mathbb Q$.
Then for any prime $p$,  $\frac 1pM$ is also a subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ and contains $M$, hence by maximality either $\frac1pM=\mathbb Q$ and $M=p\mathbb Q=\mathbb Q$ (which is absurd) or $M=\frac 1pM$. But $M=\frac1pM$ for all primes $p$ implies $M=\frac1nM$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Now if $\frac ab\in M$ with $a\ne 0$, we find $\frac 1b\in\frac 1a M=M$ and then $1=\frac1b+\ldots+\frac1b\in M$, and so $\mathbb Z\subseteq M$ and ultimately $\mathbb Q =\bigcup_n\frac 1n\mathbb Z\subseteq M$.

Let $p$ be a prime and let $M\subseteq \mathbb Q^\times$ be the set of all fractions where $p$ occurs in an even power (with positive or negative exponent). Then $M$ is a subgroup and $\mathbb Q^\times /M\cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so $M$ is maximal.

Comment: Thank you, kindly! Makes perfect sense now :).

Comment: I the first part you have to consider the possibility that $\frac{1}{2}M=M$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes I just noticed that as well ...